# onActivityResult is not called even though setResult is called

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, onactivityresult

I have an activity holding fragment (`MainActivity.java`) inside in and the fragment (`ItemFragment.java`) has recyclerview that shows some of items. When an item is cliked, It starts an activity (`ViewActivity.java`) for result. However, onActivityResult method in (`MainActivity.java`) is not called. Here is my codes

**OnClick method in ViewHolder class that starts new activity when an item is clicked**

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
      Intent i;

      // activity is an instance of AppCompatActivity class (MainActivity.java)
      i = new Intent(activity, ViewActivity.class);

      activity.startActivityForResult(i, SyncTask.REQ_CODE);
}
```

**Codes in ViewActivity that sends result**

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        ....
        resultData=new Intent();
        resultData.putExtra(SyncTask.KEY_ACTION, action);
        resultData.putExtra(SyncTask.KEY_POSITION, m.getAdapterPosition());


        setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK,resultData);
        finish();

        return true;
}
```

**onActivityResult method in `MainActivity.java`**

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    int action;
    int[] positions;

    if (requestCode == SyncTask.REQ_CODE) {
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            // Handle action

        }
    }
}
```

**Manifest file**

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.app"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="14"
    android:targetSdkVersion="21" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity android:name=".activity.MainActivity" android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light" android:name=".activity.PreferencesActivity"></activity>
    <activity android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" android:name=".activity.SignInActivity" android:label="@string/sign_in"></activity>
    <activity android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" android:name=".activity.ViewMailActivity"></activity>
</application>
```

Comment: seems should work. are you sure `setResult` invoked at runtime.

Comment: Are you using other onActivityResult in your code? I think you should call super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data) after you code inside your onActivityResult method.

Comment: I checked setResult by putting breakpoint. It is called at runtime. @heloisasim I tried it, but didn't work

Comment: Post your manifest please.

Comment: @DavidWasser I appended it to message

Comment: I'm not sure about your problem but maybe you should call the startActivityForResult directly from your activity context, and not from a fragment. Also you can try startActivityFromFragment and then when it returns to your fragment you can return to your activity

Comment: Adapter class holds instance of `MainActivity.java` and I call `startActivityForResult` from the activity instance. I will try `startActivityFromFragment`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I figured out the problem. My request code was negative and according to documentary if request code is less than 0, result is not sent.

Comment: Great that you were able to solve this and thanks for answering your own question. You can accept this as the best answer.